# Permission Error in Installing OpenCV in Anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, anaconda

i'm new to python anaconda. i decide to install opencv library to work on computer vision by this command :

```
conda install -c menpo opencv
```

but i face with this error :

```
## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - opencv


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    libopencv-3.4.2            |       h20b85fd_0        37.4 MB
    hdf5-1.8.20                |       hac2f561_1        26.7 MB
    opencv-3.4.2               |   py36h40b0b35_0          10 KB
    py-opencv-3.4.2            |   py36hc319ecb_0         1.5 MB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        65.5 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    blas:            1.0-mkl
    libopencv:       3.4.2-h20b85fd_0
    opencv:          3.4.2-py36h40b0b35_0
    py-opencv:       3.4.2-py36hc319ecb_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    ca-certificates: 2017.08.26-h94faf87_0 --> 2018.03.07-0
    certifi:         2018.1.18-py36_0      --> 2018.8.24-py36_1
    numpy:           1.14.0-py36h4a99626_1 --> 1.14.2-py36h5c71026_0
    openssl:         1.0.2n-h74b6da3_0     --> 1.0.2p-hfa6e2cd_0

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

    hdf5:            1.10.1-h98b8871_1     --> 1.8.20-hac2f561_1

Proceed ([y]/n)?


Downloading and Extracting Packages
libopencv 3.4.2: ############################################################################################## | 100%
hdf5 1.8.20: ################################################################################################## | 100%
opencv 3.4.2: ################################################################################################# | 100%
py-opencv 3.4.2: ############################################################################################## | 100%
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(481): An error occurred while uninstalling package 'defaults::numpy-1.14.0-py36h4a99626_1'.
PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied')
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied')
```

i'm running the command in Anaconda Prompt. is there any solution ? 
i tried many other installation command but above error shows up many times.
my Python is 3.6 , i use `conda info` command , and you can see the result below :

```
     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\Mohammad\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\Mohammad\.condarc
          conda version : 4.4.10
    conda-build version : 3.4.1
         python version : 3.6.4.final.0
       base environment : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3  (read only)
           channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Mohammad\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\Mohammad\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
                          C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\Mohammad\.conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.4.10 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.6.4 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.10586
          administrator : False
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Comment: Well, it could be because you don't have administrator rights

Comment: @Rick I am administrator

Comment: Well in the `conda info` it says `administrator : False`

Comment: It looks to me that you've installed Anaconda for all users and although you are the Admin, you need to open the Anaconda prompt as an Administrator and not as the current user

Answer (score 0):

You are installing conda package into "read only" directory so the permission error occur.

You have 2 choice to overcome this problem

1. Grant yourself a administrator permission .
2. Install local package into different directory inwhich you have write permission

   conda install -c menpo opencv -p YOUR_DIRECTORY

I myself prefer a 3rd choice

3. Create for yourself a new python virtual environment inside directory inwhich you have write permission and use it

   ## Create your env

   $ conda create -n YOUR_ENV -p YOUR_DIRECTORY python=2.7

   ## Load it

   source activate YOUR_ENV

   ## Install opencv

   $ conda install opencv

Hope that help

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it using these commands in the following order:

```
conda update anaconda-navigator
conda update navigator-updater
pip install opencv-python
```